# Functor has map, Monad has bind, what has filter

Tags: haskell

Functor gives us map (fmap). 
Monad gives us flatmap (bind).

What is the Haskell name for the the typeclass that provides filter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three plausible candidates are [Witherable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable), [Alternative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monadplus-1.4.2/docs/Control-Applicative-Alternative.html), and [MonadPlus](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monadplus-1.4.2/docs/Control-Monad-Plus.html).

Comment: Why Witherable rather than Filterable?

Comment: There's also `compactable`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compactable